# How to sort a column created in xls document as result adding variables

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I am working on the html table which is transformed from xml document. I added a new column - "sum" (this where is value-of $total variable) in html table where I added two column as example below and this column doesn't exist in xml file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ksiazka/osoba">

  <xsl:variable name="x1" select="kontakt/gg" />
  <xsl:variable name="x2" select="kontakt/telefon" />
  <xsl:variable name="total" select="$x1 + $x2" />

  <xsl:if test="@plec= 'm' and $total &gt; 900000000">
           <tr>
      <td><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="dane/nazwisko"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="dane/imie" /></td>
      <td>ul.<xsl:value-of select="adres/ulica" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="adres/nr-domu" /><xsl:text>/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="adres/nr-lokalu" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="kontakt/gg" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="kontakt/telefon" /></td>
      <td><xsl:variable name="hyperlink"><xsl:value-of select="kontakt/www" /></xsl:variable>
      <a href="http://{$hyperlink}"> <xsl:value-of select="kontakt/www" /></a></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$total" /></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

I would like to ask if it possible to sort the elements in

```
 <td><xsl:value-of select="$total" /></td>
```

and how to do that.
Second question is how to show elements which match some regex pattern.
Can you recommend some good materials to learn xslt ?

Edit:
Example xml file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mtczerwinski/designing-xml/master/proj3/proj3.xml

Comment: Could you show an example of your XML document, please? Also indicate if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I prefer XSLT 1.0, but 2.0 sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems strange that you would want to use a phone number as a *number*, but anyway:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="ksiazka/osoba">
        <xsl:sort select="kontakt/gg + kontakt/telefon"/>
            <xsl:variable name="total" select="kontakt/gg + kontakt/telefon" />
            <xsl:if test="@plec='m' and $total > 900000000">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="dane/nazwisko"/></td>
                    <!-- more data here -->
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$total" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="ksiazka/osoba[@plec='m' and kontakt/gg + kontakt/telefon > 900000000]">
        <xsl:sort select="kontakt/gg + kontakt/telefon"/>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="dane/nazwisko"/></td>
                    <!-- more data here -->
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="kontakt/gg + kontakt/telefon" /></td>
                </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IOW, you need to calculate the same thing two or three times.

> Second question is how to show elements which match some regex
>   pattern.

I suggest you post a separate question about that (preferably a more specific one). Note that regex is supported only in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Can you recommend some materials about regex, maybe it will help me ?

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński I am afraid I am not the right person to ask about that.